# New CSS Classes made are not been applied

Tags: html, css, asp.net, razor, visual-studio-2017

I'm having a strange issue with my CSS new classes I've made
haven't been applying the style to the elements
The elements I'm trying to apply a style is

```
<p class="Review_Title">Delicious Pizza</p>
<p class="Review_Tag">@@Restaurant Name </p>
<p class="Review_Desc">Restaurant Desc.</p>
<div class="Review_Bar"></div>
```

Here is the goal look
[image]

Here is what mine looks like

[image]

I've restarted visual studio and cleared the cache as well
When i change the class name from "Review_Title" for example to an existing Class name the style works but i keep making more classes even simple ones
that don't seem to be applying either

Here is the code below

Thanks in advance :)

Here is my Html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5" style="padding-top:60px;">
            <p class="Review_Title">Delicious Pizza</p>
            <p class="Review_Tag">@@Restaurant Name </p>
            <span style="color:#f8bd08">&#x2605; &#x2605; &#x2605; &#x2605;</span>   &#x2605;
            <p class="Review_Desc">Restaurant Desc.</p>
            <p>Review by <b>manager@asp.net</b> on <b>19/07/2016 5:41:04pm</b></p>
            <div class="Review_Bar"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is where i have my style sheet referenced

```
<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/mystyle.css" />
    <link href="~/css/elastic_grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Niconne" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Oxygen" rel="stylesheet" type="=text/css">
```

Here is the Classes that aren't working located in the mystyle.css document

```
.Review_Title{
font-size:80px;
}
.Review_Tag{
font-weight:bold;
}
.Review_Desc{
color:gray;
}
.Review_Bar {
border-bottom: 2px solid #f8bd08;
height:10px;
}
```

Here is the whole stylesheet

```
.parallax_scrolling {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #645862;
background-image: url("../images/restaurant_2.jpg");
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
color: #FFF;
cursor: default;
text-align: center;
padding:0px;
}
.parallax_scrolling_Row {
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #645862;
background-image: url("../images/restaurant_3.jpg");
background-position: center top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
color: #FFF;
cursor: default;
text-align: center;
}
.row li{
list-style-type:none;
}
.row a {
    color: #f8bd08;
}
.dark_background {
background-color: rgba(31, 20, 20, 0.6);
padding: 40px 0px;
}
.oxygen {
font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
font-size: 28px;
color: white;
letter-spacing: 5px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
margin: 60px 0px 60px 0px;
border: 2px solid #FFF;
}
.oxygen_info_banner {
font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
font-size: 26px;
color: black;
letter-spacing: 5px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
.niconne_info_banner {
font-family: 'Niconne', cursive;
color: #f8bd08;
font-size: 55px;
}
.lato {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-size: 28px;
}
.niconne {
font-family: 'Niconne', cursive;
color: #f8bd08;
font-size: 65px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 400;
}
.niconne_Row {
font-family: 'Niconne', cursive;
color: #f8bd08;
font-size: 50px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 400;
}
.title_banner {
border-top: 2px solid #f8bd08;
border-bottom: 2px solid #f8bd08;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
margin-top:30px;
margin-bottom:30px;
font-family: 'Niconne', cursive;
color: #f8bd08;
font-size: 60px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: 400;
}
.title_banner h1 {
font-size:50px;
}
.collapse_Box {
border:none;
}
.review_box {
background-color:Highlight;
height:500px;
}
#Italian_Button_Dropdown{
border:1px solid gray;
background-color:lightgray;
border-radius:4px;
padding:6px;
}
#Italian_dropdown {
border:2px solid gray;
border-width:0px 1px 1px 1px;

}
#Asian_dropdown {
border: 2px solid gray;
border-width: 0px 1px 1px 1px;
}
.Review_Title{
font-size:80px;

}
.Review_Tag{
font-weight:bold;
}
.Review_Desc{
color:gray;
} 
.Review_Bar {
border-bottom: 2px solid #f8bd08;
height:10px;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your CSS (though you should generally avoid uppercase unless you really need to use it) so it must be the stylesheet is not being applied. Do you have errors in your browser console?

Comment: No errors in the console :(
I have styles working correctly on the same page from the same sheet 
I notice i have a title that is grabbing its styles correctly from the sheet
https://i.gyazo.com/0b501339e58a8d535422a8be7e2b83c5.png

But when i see the "Review_Title" Element it dosnt see the class

https://i.gyazo.com/0757ec5c7b294ebd6c2f1409c24b8e89.png

Comment: So if you click on "mystyle.css" in the Chrome tools, it will bring up your CSS file - does that file have the missing CSS attributes?

Comment: :O you're right the classes aren't listed in mystyle.css under the sources 
https://i.gyazo.com/e5aec5981cbad64bd385079045b2d9d1.png

Comment: So are you sure you're editing the right file? Check the paths etc.

Comment: :) WELP i just cleared the browsing Data and it worked >_<

Comment: Useful advice when working with CSS: There's an option in the Chrome dev tools to never use the cache when the dev tools are open - I find that super useful so I don't need to keep clearing the cache!

Comment: Legend thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use Inspect mode in your browser to check those HTML elements and related styles u created.
2. I saw that u didnt create any buttons in your Review_Bar class
3. If u cant find any CSS related to your element in the first steps, you'd better check the path to your CSS files